# Prevent disconnected display from merging windows into the active one

Tags: windows, winapi, gdi

I've got a personal laptop (running Windows 10) which I use at work where I connect it to an external display using **extended display mode**. I keep all my personal icons and windows on my laptop display and store all the work-related windows on the external display. Whenever I unplug it, all the windows and icons from that display are merged into my laptop screen. I want to **programmatically** prevent changing anything on my primary screen when the secondary is disconnected. I'm currently writing a utility app for a variety of small productivity improving features and would like to add such feature in it. I can think of two ways to achieve this:

- by tricking the system to think that the external display hasn't been
  disconnected;
- or take all the opened windows and icons on disconnected screen and put them on separate virtual desktop.

I was looking into Windows GDI Device Context Functions but haven't found anything about display connection/disconnection events. How can I detect display disconnection (and get that display's opened windows and icons)? Anything that can be done using C#, C++ or PowerShell scripts would be much appreciated!

Comment: And were all those work-related windows are supposed to go in this case?

Comment: Have you checked [`WM_DISPLAYCHANGE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145210(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`WM_DEVICECHANGE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363480(v=vs.85).aspx)? Raymond Chen has [some code to get / set the desktop icon positions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130318-00/?p=4933). For the windows there is [`GetWindowPlacement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633518(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @VTT the windows from disconnected monitor should either remain hidden (and re-appear when user click it's icon on a taskbar), or (parhaps the better option) a new virtual desktop should be created where all those windows would go to.

Comment: @zett42 thank you for the hints! I've made some progress and if/when I get a complete solution, I'll post an answer here.